# Why $E$ is neglected at large and small $r$ of quantum harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, approximations, asymptotics

In obtaining radial solution of quantum oscillator why E is neglected?

Radial equation:
[image]

[image]

Resource: nouredine zettili.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does this because the original differential equation is overly difficult to solve without first examining the boundary conditions.

The point here is that you are *initially* only approximately solving the TISE in the regimes of small $r$ or large $r$.  This is where the boundary conditions are, so you want to get the correct behaviours at these boundaries.  For finite energy, the dominant term is, in one case, the $1/r^2$ term (assuming $\ell\ne 0$), and in the other case the $r^2$ term.
Once you have the correct behaviour near $r=0$ and at $r\to\infty$, the strategy is then to interpolate between small $r$ and large $r$ using a polynomial.

Thus you start with small $r$ (or Eq.(6.86)), and then go to large $r$ (or Eq.(6.87)) and this gives you a solution of the form
$$
U(r)\sim r^{\ell+1} e^{-\lambda r^2}f(r)\, , \tag{1}
$$
for some unknown polynomial $f$.  This way, you are *guaranteed* that the $U(r)$ you find will satisfy the correct boundary conditions.
You then plug (1) into the full TISE to get a differential equation for the unknown function $f$, which can be solved (after some gymnastics) by identification with a standard differential equation.

This is similar to the 1d harmonic oscillator, except there is no condition the solution for small $r$: in 3d you need this solution to go to $0$ smoothly since the system cannot have “negative values of $r$”.  In the 1d case, there is a condition at $r\to\infty$ and one often starts there to get the right behaviour, then interpolate back to finite $r$s.

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is neglected because in both cases (where $r \rightarrow 0$ and when $r \rightarrow \infty$) there is a term multiplying $U(r)$ that gets very large when compared to the constant $E$.
When $r \rightarrow 0$, this is the term which depends on $\frac{1}{r^2}$; when $r \rightarrow \infty$ this is the term which depends on $r^2$.